# Read scientific notation scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am developing a program which should have only one scanf function and it should be able to accept input in scientific notation and real numbers.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A more direct person would tell you to RTFM.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342982/reading-scientific-notation-in-c

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.  Your best option is to review what was recently talked about in class.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`scanf` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

`%f` matches a floating-point number. The format of the number is the same as expected by `strtof()`.

Looking at the [`strtof` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)

(optional) `e` or `E` followed with optional minus or plus sign and nonempty sequence of decimal digits (defines exponent)

Thus, you can use the `%f` specifier to read numbers in `e` notation. That is, 
`1e-3` is `1 * 10 ^ -3`.