# How to parse a text file that have both numbers and text in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I want to parse the text file below. I'm a little bit confused about the format of this text file since it includes text and numbers. I would like to store the first 6 lines (only the numbers) in a variable to be later used on my code. Then I would like to parse the rest of the data into a 2D array format.

Example of the text file:

```
Resistance per unit length (ohm/um): 0.0165
Capacitance per unit length (F/um): 1.8400e-016
Sink node capacitance (F): 2.500000e-016
Buffer output resistance (ohm): 0.01
Sinkcount: 267
Nodecount: 965

%thisnode  parnode  lcnode  rcnode  length(um)  xloc(um)  yloc(um)

1 534 -1 -1 405.080000 29322.000000 41420.000000
2 535 -1 -1 1635.360000 26208.000000 51579.000000
3 536 -1 -1 561.000000 35565.000000 61661.000000
4 537 -1 -1 223.150000 36852.000000 64281.000000
5 538 -1 -1 648.000000 33416.000000 62525.000000
6 539 -1 -1 1828.300000 36915.000000 67124.000000
7 270 -1 -1 126.700000 32275.000000 58078.000000
8 327 -1 -1 1358.200000 30591.000000 67258.000000
9 540 -1 -1 648.000000 33180.000000 61229.000000
10 541 -1 -1 3871.620000 43063.000000 69393.000000
11 314 -1 -1 1084.900000 36871.000000 61100.000000
12 542 -1 -1 4248.380000 43027.000000 61273.000000
13 543 -1 -1 2887.870000 51342.000000 60304.000000
14 349 -1 -1 1500.600000 48402.000000 50963.000000
15 544 -1 -1 731.400000 47169.000000 48731.000000
16 545 -1 -1 2865.890000 52320.000000 39499.000000
17 546 -1 -1 104.000000 53329.000000 36125.000000
18 336 -1 -1 1290.400000 50974.000000 41565.000000
19 547 -1 -1 294.090000 54258.000000 39095.000000
20 548 -1 -1 2206.560000 63990.000000 36007.000000
21 348 -1 -1 1337.200000 57164.000000 37226.000000
22 906 -1 -1 718.500000 52707.000000 34101.000000
23 550 -1 -1 380.310000 49281.000000 28791.000000
24 382 -1 -1 1814.700000 46469.000000 31039.000000
25 551 -1 -1 1.000000 37908.000000 21556.000000
26 552 -1 -1 1272.020000 34929.000000 27721.000000
27 553 -1 -1 984.000000 34185.000000 24396.000000
28 554 -1 -1 945.300000 37959.000000 29214.000000
29 325 -1 -1 1153.400000 44933.000000 26816.000000
30 555 -1 -1 181.600000 41203.000000 23650.000000
31 389 -1 -1 2206.700000 47123.000000 25155.000000
32 556 -1 -1 411.290000 45869.000000 32701.000000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read scientific notation scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422281/read-scientific-notation-scanf)

Comment: not really, I need help with actually how to start the code to parse this text file above

Comment: @mmm, can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58938028/edit) and include the code you have already written? As written, your question and subsequent comment read as "I need someone to write this code for me."

Comment: Read each line using `fgets()` or `getline()`, then parse it depending on what it starts with.